# How Draw Animated Polyline?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-animation, ui-thread, google-polyline

I was written some code for draw and remove polyline. in thread(**Handler().postDelayed()**)than it's look like animated polyline but i think  it's not better approach.

Can anyone please help me with a suitable solution?

Comment: what do u want to do?

Comment: i want draw animated(**repted**) polyline.Draw and remove 5 time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create one polyline like this:

```
PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions().width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
for (int z = 0; z < list.size(); z++) {
    LatLng point = list.get(z);
    options.add(point);
}
line = myMap.addPolyline(options);
```

Comment: I want animated polyline.

Comment: dude, you should rewrite your question if you need some positive responses. Also, post some code to show your efforts so we can help you more.